# How to re-create uploading something like Facebook Timeline cover?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I found several plugins that crops the image, but doesn't have the uploading function.

Here are those plugins:

[TMatthew JWindowCrop](http://www.tmatthew.net/jwindowcrop)

[imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)

So, how do I put the uploading function on JavaScript, I heard you can use it as a "Server-Side Language" (node.js) or should I use a different language like PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=basic), files for download contains sample php script to get you started and many samples here on stack.